# Trying to get data using Websocket & run some parallel code on the value returned using Asyncio

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, python-asyncio

I am just getting started with asyncio in python. What I am trying to do is below :

1. A Websocket connects to a data provider and keeps listening for new data (Run forever )
2. Parallelly work on this data and maybe save the data to a file. Make buy /sell decisions(Any parellel operation is okay)
3. Trying to use asyncio to achieve this (Will threads be better? Although threads seem more complicated that asyncio )
   I am Using jupyter notebook( So Event loop is already created, maybe that's the problem ?)

Code 1 works ,  but this blocks my event loop and only keeps printing the data. All other code is blocked. Since its always busy in the web socket I guess.

```
import ssl
import websocket
import json
from IPython.display import display, clear_output
from threading import Thread

def on_message(ws, message):
    resp1 = json.loads(message)
    clear_output(wait=True)
    print(resp1['events'][0]['price'])

def run():
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://api.gemini.com/v1/marketdata/BTCUSD",on_message=on_message)
    ws.run_forever(sslopt={"cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_NONE})

ws_run = Thread(target=run)
ws_run.start()

print("ok") # this prints once, but then it gets blocked by the websocket code.
```

I tried code 2 :
But this hangs forever and doesn't do anything.

```
import asyncio
import ssl
import websocket
import json
from IPython.display import display, clear_output


async def on_message(ws, message):
    resp1 = json.loads(message)
    clear_output(wait=True)
    #print(resp1,sort_keys=True, indent=4)
    #print(resp1['events'][0]['side'])
    print(resp1['events'][0]['price'])
    
async def count2(x):
    x=0
    for i in range(5):
        await asyncio.sleep(0.01)    
        print('second' , x)
        y=x+10
    return y


async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(count(x), on_message(ws, message))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import time
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://api.gemini.com/v1/marketdata/BTCUSD",on_message=on_message)
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever(ws.run_forever(sslopt={"cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_NONE}))
    s = time.perf_counter()
    await main()
    elapsed = time.perf_counter() - s
    print(f" executed in {elapsed:0.2f} seconds.")
```

Tried this variant in main(), still no response. :

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import time
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://api.gemini.com/v1/marketdata/BTCUSD",on_message=on_message)
    ws.run_forever(sslopt={"cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_NONE})
    s = time.perf_counter()
    await main()
    elapsed = time.perf_counter() - s
    print(f" executed in {elapsed:0.2f} seconds.")
```

Update: I got this to work ,but I dont know if this is the right way, without using run_forever():

```
import ssl
import websocket
import asyncio
import time


async def MySock():
    while True:
        print(ws.recv())
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
    
async def MyPrint():
    while True:
        print("-------------------------------------------") 
        
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)

    

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(MySock(),MyPrint())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ws = websocket.WebSocket()
    ws.connect("wss://api.gemini.com/v1/marketdata/btcusd?top_of_book=true&offers=true")
    s = time.perf_counter()
    await main()
    elapsed = time.perf_counter() - s
    print(f" executed in {elapsed:0.2f} seconds.")
```